# gnu makefile value to variable, but only if it does not already contain it

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu

So based on certain criteria I want to append to a variable, lets say:

`LIST += BOB`

But there could be more then one place where I might want to add BOB, so lets take the following code snippet:

```
LIST += BOB
LIST += FRED
LIST += TED
LIST += BOB
```

I want to end up with LIST containing `BOB FRED TED` so I don't want the duplicate additional BOB. I also want to keep the order (otherwise I think I could have used `sort`).

Is there a clever way to do this? - I guess I can just search for the text in the variable first, but it seems long winded. So is there a "append if not already existing" type function?

Comment: If  `LIST` is simply expanded (`LIST :=`) you could just `LIST += $(filter-out $(LIST),BOB)`...

Comment: @RenaudPacalet that should work, only makefile does not let me recursivly reference the variable LIST

Comment: @RenaudPacalet hang on ... you just updated your comment... let me try

Comment: Because it will work only with simply expanded variables. See my answer.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet ah cool - I have mis-understood `:=`. Is it true that once you expand using `:=` it (the variable) stays simply expanded for its life time?... thats a nice trick : )

Comment: Yes, if a variable is declared as simply expanded it remains so, unless you change it with `LIST = ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  `LIST` is simply expanded (`LIST :=`) you could just `LIST += $(filter-out $(LIST),BOB)`:

```
$ cat Makefile
LIST :=
LIST += $(filter-out $(LIST),BOB)
LIST += $(filter-out $(LIST),FRED)
LIST += $(filter-out $(LIST),TED)
LIST += $(filter-out $(LIST),BOB)

all:
    $(info $(LIST))
$ make
 BOB FRED TED 
make: 'all' is up to date.
```

**Note:** If a variable is declared as simply expanded it remains so, unless you change it, e.g. with `LIST = ...`

Comment: Thanks for that, hope you don't mind, I just added that last little comment as a note in the answer at the bottom

Comment: No problem, it's probably better with the note.